# Simple OData Client - create OrderBy expression at runtime?

Tags: odata

**Simple OData** queries are straightforward if everything is known at compile time. I have learned how to build expressions at runtime for purposes of filtering, but I have not quite figured out how to build an OrderBy expression at runtime?

Example mockup of a query (dynamic filter expression):

```
var empls = await client.For<MyModel>("MyTable")
                    .Top(request.PageSize)
                    .Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize)
                    .Filter(filter)
                    .FindEntriesAsync();
```

If I knew at compile time what order was needed I could add a .OrderBy() clause. But since the user decides the sorting at runtime, I need to build an expression for ordering.

To dynamically build the filter passed above I used ODataExpression<> object. I'm looking for equivalent capability to pass to an order clause (if that exists?).

Comment: Huh what do you mean? Odata is meant for dynamic filtering so it operates at run time.  You're suppose to use to Odata metadata to build the query.

Comment: I'll illustrate by example. I have an MVC controller method used by the Kendo grid to query for data. If I am confident that there will only be a reasonable number of records to return to the grid, i can return them all and let the grid manage filtering and sorting client-side. BUT, if I implement server-side paging, that means that server-side code needs to manage filtering and sorting based on what the grid passes in for filters and sorts (in response to user actions on the grid).

Comment: Treat them the same way.  1. Set the page size high enough say for those endpoints so that they're returned all in a single page.  2.  OData has paging and filtering built into it e.g  `Products?$top=10&$skip=20` 3. You can apply an ODataQuery to an existing IQueryable, e.g have your controller take in an `ODataQueryOptions<Product> options` and then you can call `options.ApplyTo(_products.AsQueryable())`

Comment: The whole point is to deal with an unknown number of records, thousands maybe millions. I can't necessarily load all records at once. User decides the page size. Paging is not the question. OrderBy is the only question to be resolved at this point.

Comment: What are you confused on?  OData provides metadata which will allow you to build the filter from the client.   You're manually trying to apply a filter in the api.  Probably because the default implementation has its limitations. so pass your default query to the QueryOptions and use apply to which will handle the filtering and sorting.

Comment: Would you mind illustrating an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: Okay Give me a second ill post one now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed another OrderBy() overload of the Fluent client interface:

```
OrderBy(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> columns);
```

If you need dynamic multi-level ordering, you can create a List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> and populate it with KeyValuePair<string, bool> objects where the string is the field specification and the bool is false for ASCENDING and true for DESCENDING sorts.

Just be sure that your string uses the forward slash "/" as the field path separator rather than the period.

Sorting hierarchy will be in the order that you added the KeyValuePairs to the list. So if you want to sort by:

1. Person.LastName ASC
2. Person.FirstName ASC
3. Person.EmployerName DESC

you just add the objects to the list in the above order, as you would expect passing false, false, true for the booleans.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to compose and execute the OData request in a single statement. The Simple OData APIs are designed to allow you to selectively build the query to implement your business logic as you go.

The choice between *Ascending* and *Descending* needs to be known, as does the name of the column (or columns) you want to sort on, the details of these haven't been provided in the original post so here I will assume that the `sortColumn` is a string that defines the column the user has selected and `sortDescending` is a flag that indicates if the sort direction is in *Ascending* (`false`) or *Descending* (`True`) order.

```
var query = client.For<MyModel>("MyTable")
                  .Top(request.PageSize)
                  .Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize)
                  .Filter(filter);
if (sortDescending)
    query = query.OrderByDescending(sortColumn);
else
    query = query.OrderBy(sortColumn);

var empls = await query.FindEntriesAsync();
```

---

There are other techniques that can be used to achieve a similar outcome, however their suitability greatly depends on how you store the columns to be sorted, if you allow multi-column sorting and if you allow different directions in your multi-column sort.

Comment: There can actually be multiple sort columns. When I wrote the OP I hadn't understood yet that you can call Filter and OrderBy multiple times (absolutely NONE of the examples I saw online or in our code did that).  Calling Filter multiple times, of course, behaves like an AND operation. I will test, but at this point I assume calling OrderBy a second time will have same effect as adding comma between clauses in SQL query.

Comment: @jrichview actually adding multiple calls to Order By will have the same effect of reversing the clauses in SQL, so be careful the order that you call them in, otherwise you should use `.ThenBy()` or you can use the array overload to `OrderBy(string[] columns)` to specify all the columns with the expected priorities.

Comment: ...and/or ThenByDescending().  Actually in our situation the only time there will be multiple is when not sorting by the person's lastname/firstname then their name will be added automatically as a secondary sort. Pretty common case, really.

Comment: Although I seem to be able to pass a string field name to the OrderBy() clause, if I try to pass it to the ThenBy() clause it flags it as an error, because ThenBy() has no overload that accepts strings.  Apparently you have to build an expression object.